# Getting schema with key or id already exists error while using Angular6-json-schema-form library

Tags: angular6, angular6-json-schema-form

I am using Angular6-json-schema-form library and included

`import { Bootstrap4FrameworkModule } from 'angular6-json-schema-form'`
in the app.module.ts file. Also i created a JSON schema object in the component file and used the below in the app.component.html file

```
<json-schema-form loadExternalAssets="true" [schema]="yourschema" framework="bootstrap-4"></json-schema-form>
```

But when i do npm start and do a localhost i am getting an error in the console

```
ERROR Error: schema with key or id "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema" already exists
```

Can anyone please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: Try to perform below commands in command prompts :  rm -rf /node_modules
and after that installing the packages again by
npm install

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there are two JSON schemas within your project both having the id of "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema". There could be two reasons for this:

1. There is actually another JSON schema file you are using with the same exact id.
2. There is only one schema with this id but the framework is having a hard time reading your $id off the schema. We also had some difficulties reading $id with this framework back in our team. try removing the $id and its value and re-run your app.